# #VALUE returned in Excel when calling VBA Function

Tags: excel, vba

Hopefully someone can assist.  I'm reviewing some VBA code, not my own and the following Function is returning a #VALUE in Excel.  If I go into the cell and hit enter, the date does pull through correctly.

```
Public Function NextWorkingDay(ReportDate)

' Assumes that all dates are consistent across spreadsheets
' Calculates the next working day of a date shown

Set ToSheet = Sheets("I." & MnemonicList(1))
strReportDate = Format(ReportDate, "ddd dd/mm/yyyy")
Set ToRow = ToSheet.Range("MvtDates").Find(What:=strReportDate, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

Application.StatusBar = "Calculating next working day."
Count = 1
TempRow = 0
Found = False

Do While Not Found

    TempRow = ToRow.Row + Count

    If ToSheet.Cells(TempRow, ToRow.Column + 1) = 1 Then
        Found = True
        NextWorkingDay = ReportDate + Count
    Else
        Count = Count + 1
    End If

    If Count = 10 Then
        MsgBox ("Error finding next working day")
    End If

Loop


End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by this "If I go into the cell and hit enter, the date does pull through correctly"? Is it sometimes showing an error and sometimes working correctly?

Comment: What is `MnemonicList(1)`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We are not able to run the code at all, let alone debug it. There is a good chance that the problem (whatever it is) doesn't lie in this function per se but instead e.g. involves interaction between the function and some event handler

Comment: The behavior you are describing makes me suspect that the Sheet's calculation mode is not automatic. Check the sheet's calculation mode and see if it is set to manual. If yes, change it to automatic and then test.

Comment: Cal your function from a sub and you'll be able to debug it and find the error.

Comment: Thanks all, obviously new to the forum, I will look to update this.

Comment: Is "." a valid character in a sheet name?